# Update in C# using repository, new window and main window

Tags: c#, ms-access

This is my code used for updating a customer in c#, can someone help me correcting the code, so that it will work smoothly?

This is my repository code:

```
public static void KlantWijzigen(Klant klan)
{
    string commandString = string.Format("UPDATE tblKlanten (Adres, Postcode, Gemeente, Email, Telefoonnummer) SET('{0}','{1}','{2}','{3}','{4}')", klan.Adres, klan.Postcode, klan.Gemeente, klan.Email, klan.Telefoonnummer);

    OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(connectionString);
    OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
    OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter();

    conn.Open();

    //commandstring toevoegen aan adapter
    command.Connection = conn;
    command.CommandText = commandString;
    adapter.UpdateCommand = command;

    //command uitvoeren
    adapter.UpdateCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

    //databank connect
    conn.Close();
}
```

My new window code:

```
public partial class WindowKlantWijzig : Window
{
    public WindowKlantWijzig()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void buttonSlaOp_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Klant upda = new Klant();

        upda.Naam = textBoxNieuweNaam.Text;
        upda.Adres = textBoxAdresNieuw.Text;
        upda.Postcode = Convert.ToInt32(textBoxPostcodeNieuw.Text);
        upda.Gemeente = textBoxGemeenteNieuw.Text;
        upda.Email = textBoxEmailNieuw.Text;
        upda.Telefoonnummer = textBoxTelefoonnummerNieuw.Text;

        KlantRepository.KlantWijzigen(upda);
        MessageBox.Show("De klant werd succesvol gewijzigd");
    }
}
```

And this is my main window code

```
private void buttonWijzigKlant_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (comboBoxKlanten.SelectedIndex == -1)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Selecteer de klant die je wil wijzigen");
    }
    else
    {
        // TODO: gebruiker eerst om bevestiging vragen
        Klant klan = (Klant)comboBoxKlanten.SelectedItem;
        KlantRepository.KlantWijzigen(klan);
        MessageBox.Show("De klant werd succesvol gewijzigd");

        //combobox wordt vernieuwd
        comboBoxKlanten.ItemsSource = null;
        comboBoxKlanten.ItemsSource = KlantRepository.AlleKlanten();
    }
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve here? What issue are you facing?

Comment: Also, `string commandString = string.Format("UPDATE tblKlanten (Adres, Postcode, Gemeente, Email, Telefoonnummer) SET('{0}','{1}','{2}','{3}','{4}')", klan.Adres, klan.Postcode, klan.Gemeente, klan.Email, klan.Telefoonnummer);` is a SQL injection vulnerablility.

Comment: i'm trying to achieve that I can update records in the database. But the update must be carried out in a new window, so I can update and confirm the update in that new window.

Comment: Have you any suggestion how i can avoid the SQL injection? i'm just a newbie in programming, and this is my first programming project

Comment: You should use: `command.Parameters.Add("Adres", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = klan.Adres;`

Comment: Jeroen: Can you please inform me where I should type that code, and maybe which code is unnecessary?

Comment: @JefD Added an example as answer. Veel succes ;-)

Answer (score 0):

As response on the question from the comments, I would do it like this: *(untested/pseudo)* **So this is NOT the answer**, but a response to prevent SQL-injections.

```
public static void KlantWijzigen(Klant klan)
{
    string commandString = "UPDATE tblKlanten (Adres, Postcode, Gemeente, Email, Telefoonnummer) SET(@Adres, @Postcode, @Gemeente, @Email, @Telefoonnummer)";

    using(OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(connectionString))
    using(OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand())
    {
        conn.Open();

        //commandstring toevoegen aan adapter
        command.Connection = conn;
        command.CommandText = commandString;

        // de velden zetten via de parameters, zodat SQL-injection niet werkt.
        command.Parameters.Add("Adres", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = klan.Adres;
        command.Parameters.Add("Postcode", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = klan.Postcode;
        command.Parameters.Add("Gemeente", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = klan.Gemeente;
        command.Parameters.Add("Email", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = klan.Email;
        command.Parameters.Add("Telefoonnummer", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = klan.Telefoonnummer;

        OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter();

        adapter.UpdateCommand = command;

        //command uitvoeren
        adapter.UpdateCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

Don't forget... you're missing a `Where` clause.. so you are updating **ALL** records.

You might change (something like):

```
    string commandString = @"
        UPDATE tblKlanten (Adres, Postcode, Gemeente, Email, Telefoonnummer)            
        SET(@Adres, @Postcode, @Gemeente, @Email, @Telefoonnummer) 
        WHERE id = @Id";   // <<--------------

    command.Parameters.Add("Id", OleDbType.Integer).Value = klan.Id;
```

Comment: Harteljik bedankt voor de duidelijke uitwerking, ik ga er vanavond na lestijd mee aan de slag. Bedankt!

Comment: Graag gedaan...vergeet niet de WHERE, anders wordt al je data aangepast...